# Como pasar valores mediante AJAX de un Select usando el ONCHANGE

Tags: php, html, ajax

tengo este .php que manda el valor escogido de un select

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>pasar valores con ajax</title>
// Aquí esta la referencia a jquery
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('ready',function(){

  $('#btn-ingresar').click(function(){
    var url = "buscar2.php";                                      

    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                    
       data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
       success: function(data)            
       {
         $('#resp').html(data);           
       }
     });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
 <body>
   <form method="post" id="formulario">
    <select name="estado" id="estado" >
      <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
      <option value="Cerrado">Cerrado</option>
      <option value="Asignado">Asignado</option>
      <option value="En Curso">En Curso</option>
 </select>
    <input type="button" id="btn-ingresar" value="Ingresar" />
</form>

<div id="resp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

entonces pasamos al buscar2.php en donde imprimos la variable

```
  <?php   
      $estado= $_POST['estado'];

      echo "el estado es: ".$estado; 
  ?>
```

pero lo que deseo es no usar el boton, sino que mediante el ONCHANGE  del select se envie inmediatamente...¿se puede realizar esta ejecucion?

Comment: a estudiar JavaScript en https://developer.mozilla.org/es-Es/ y http://www.freecodecamp.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al hacer el siguiente script te enviara el post, al hacer el cambio

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>pasar valores con ajax</title>
// Aquí esta la referencia a jquery
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('ready',function(){

  $('#estado').on('change',function(){
    var url = "buscar2.php";                                      

    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                    
       data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
       success: function(data)            
       {
         $('#resp').html(data);           
       }
     });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
 <body>
   <form method="post" id="formulario">
    <select name="estado" id="estado" >
      <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
      <option value="Cerrado">Cerrado</option>
      <option value="Asignado">Asignado</option>
      <option value="En Curso">En Curso</option>
 </select>
    <input type="button" id="btn-ingresar" value="Ingresar" />
</form>

<div id="resp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

puedes leer mas sobre la documentacion 'on' en el siguiente link 
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: en el select queda <select name="estado" id="estado">... ????

Comment: así es, lo demás queda igual solo cambia la función click del button

Comment: en lo que publicaste veo que eliminaste el $(document).on('ready',function(){)

Comment: dejame poner todo el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente cambia tu click handler por esto:

```
$('#estado').on("change", function(){
```

Comment: en el select queda <select name="estado" id="estado">... ????

Comment: Si, todo queda igual excepto eso

Answer (score 0):

La implementación podría ser de la siguiente manera

```
$('#estado').change(function(){
    var data= $(this).val();
    buscar(data);
});

function(data){
    $.ajax({                        
        type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                    
       data: data,
       success: function(response) {
           console.log(response)           
       }
    });
}
```

En su caso no es necesario enviar todo el formualario sino solo el valor que capturó el select, ya en su PHP puedes obtener el valor por medio de `$_POST`